# Find angle in triangle with incenter

Tags: geometry

> In a triangle $ABC$ if $AD$, $BE$, $CF$ are the angle bisectors of $\angle A$, $\angle B$ $\angle C$ respectively with incenter $I$ and $\angle A=120^\circ$ Find $\angle DFI$

[image]
It's $30^\circ$. If $BE$ meet $DF$ at $G$ and $CF$ meet $DE$ at $H$ it seem that $\triangle GEI$ and $\triangle HFI$ is an isosceles triangle. And also $GA$ and $HA$ is the angle bisector of $\angle BAD$ and $\angle CAD$ respectively. I dun know how to prove all of these, I just put it in GeoGebra and see the accurate picture, all I could find is $\angle BIC=150^\circ$, $\angle BIF=30^\circ$ and $\angle DFI+\angle DEI=60^\circ$. Please help

Comment: Can you clarify what are the 2 circles doing in the image? They don't appear in the problem statement.

Comment: @CalvinLin that is just my sketch. Because triangle $GFI$ and $HIE$ is isosceles but I dun know why too

Comment: @cosmo5 my teacher gave it to me to solve it in 2 days, deadline is today and I can't still figuring out how to solve it

Comment: @CalvinLin I add some more information about point $G$ and $H$ please take a look

Comment: @user635988 If it's given GA and HA are angle bisectors, then two smaller circles are incircles of smaller triangles. They do not exceed the smaller triangles and they do not intersect at I.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

In $\triangle BCD, \, $ $CA$ is the external angle bisector of $\angle DCH \, $ and $BE \,$ is the internal angle bisector of $\angle DBC$ and that makes point $E$ as the ex-center. Hence $DE$ is the external angle bisector of $\angle ADC$.

(**As the bisectors of the external angles on one side of a triangle and the bisector of the opposite internal angle are concurrent** and in this case the concurrency point is $E$).

say $\angle BEC = \alpha, \angle DEB = \beta$

Then $\angle CDE = 180^0 - (60^0 + \alpha + \beta) = 120^0 - \alpha -\beta \,$ (in $\triangle CED$)

Also $\angle ADE = \angle DEB + \angle DBE = \beta + \angle CBE = 60^0 - \alpha + \beta$

As $\angle CDE = \angle ADE, \angle DEB = \beta = 30^0$

By the way, in any triangle with $\angle C$ as $120^0$, the angle bisector of $\angle C$ meeting at point $D$ on $AB$ will make a right angle with the points where other two angle bisectors meet the other two sides of the triangle.

Comment: Is it true for any two external bisectors and opposite internal bisector, that they meet at a point, just like internal bisectors? Where can I read more about it?

Comment: Yes that is true, just like internal angle bisectors. There are $3$ ex-centers and it is called ex-center because it is the center of the external circle tangent to sides ( / extended sides) of the triangle. You can check Triangles section - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection#:~:text=The%20exterior%20or%20external%20bisector,side%2C%20into%20two%20equal%20angles.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Construct an equilateral triangle $CFK$.

Since $\angle FAC + \angle FKC = 180^\circ$, $AFKC$ is a cyclic quadrilateral.
$\Rightarrow \angle FAK = \angle FCK = 60^\circ = \angle FAD$
$\Rightarrow AIDK$ is a straight line.
$\Rightarrow \angle DKC = \angle AFC = 180^\circ - \angle FAC - \angle ACF = 60^\circ - \frac{\angle C}{2} = \angle DCK$
$\Rightarrow DK = DC$
$\Rightarrow \triangle FDK \cong \triangle FDC$
$\Rightarrow \angle DFI = \frac{60 ^\circ}{2} = 30^\circ$

Comment: That's some nice solution you got there! Thank you very much! Could you tell me what's behind the idea of the construction?

Comment: Thanks. The idea came from 120° + 60° = 180° ( cyclic quadrilateral ) and 30° + 30° = 60° ( 2 ∠DFI ).

Comment: But Math Lover's solution is more easier to learn.